# Selecting div with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello I have such an html, when I parse it with Beautiful Soup I am not able to select the  class text. Think that the problem is in  as nested tags are not recognized as children of it.
How can I select the span tag text?

Thanks

```
<div data-component="new_enquiry_form_app" data-props="{"isTelRequired":false,"placement":"top",}">
  <section class="enquiry-form-box__wrapper">
    <div class="enquiry-form-box enquiry-form-box--inverted"> 
      <form class="enquiry-form-box__form" tabindex="-1">
        <fieldset class="enquiry-form-box__wrapper">
          <div class="enquiry-form-box__fields">
            <div class="k-ns">
              <span class="text-gray block mt-3 font-bold text-sm">Property reference: 412</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: What text do you want? `Property reference: 412` ?

Comment: @MendelG yes Property reference: 412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div data-component="new_enquiry_form_app" data-props="{"isTelRequired":false,"placement":"top",}">
  <section class="enquiry-form-box__wrapper">
    <div class="enquiry-form-box enquiry-form-box--inverted"> 
      <form class="enquiry-form-box__form" tabindex="-1">
        <fieldset class="enquiry-form-box__wrapper">
          <div class="enquiry-form-box__fields">
            <div class="k-ns">
              <span class="text-gray block mt-3 font-bold text-sm">Property reference: 412</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
span = soup.select_one('span.text-gray.block.mt-3.font-bold.text-sm')
print(span.get_text())
```

prints:

```
Property reference: 412
```

Then this is one way:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='c:program/geckodriver')
driver.get('https://www.kyero.com/en/property/7689206-villa-for-sale-sant-joan-de-labritja')

span = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.text-gray.block.mt-3.font-bold.text-sm')
print(span.text)
driver.close()
```

prints:

```
Property reference: 412
```

Note yo need [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and in this code geckodriver is set to be imported from `c:/program/geckodriver.exe`
@Andrej Kesely was faster with the other answer so i give a selenium answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this code alone prints "Property reference: 412" but when I try on whole webpage that prints None, unfortunately.

Comment: Then give me the url @Arthur

Comment: Updated my answer @Arthur

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm still curious, why there is  no way to just select the span, or div in this situation, like in others?

Comment: The data is loaded with JavaScript and requests  don't run JavaScripts

Answer (score 1):

To print the reference label, you can use this script (the data is stored in javascript variable inside the HTML document):

```
import re
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.kyero.com/en/property/7689206-villa-for-sale-sant-joan-de-labritja'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
html_text = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
data = json.loads( re.search(r'window\.initialState = (.*);', html_text).group(1) )

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data['property']['referenceLabel'])
```

Prints:

```
Property reference: 412
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!